# TYPO3 - Access _localizedUid property in fluid

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase, typo3-8.x, typo3-8.7.x

With {newsItem.uid} I can access the uid of an record. But how can I access _localizedUid ?

```
<f:debug>{newsItem}</f:debug>

uid => protected 74 (integer)
_localizedUid => protected 77 (integer) modified
_languageUid => protected 1 (integer) modified
_versionedUid => protected 74 (integer) modified
pid => protected 33 (integer)
```

js:

```
<script>                
    var jobID = '{newsItem.uid}';
    console.log('JobID: '+jobID);
    var jobIDlocal = '{newsItem.localizedUid}';
    console.log('Localized: '+jobIDlocal);
</script>
```

Console:

```
JobID: 74
Localized:
```

Answer (score 2):

In your Controller Action:

```
$this->view->assign('localizedUid', $mymodelobject->_getProperty('_localizedUid'));
```

Then you can use `{localizedUid}` in your fluid templates.

Answer (score 1):

**Path of Jesus:** In order to access internal fields of a model, you have to add this property in the Model.php (in case of news you have to extend the News model).

I don't know how a model property must be spellend if it begins with an underscore but it should be **one of these** names in the Model:

`protected $LocalizedUid = 0;
// or
protected $_localizedUid = 0;
// or
protected $localizedUid = 0;`

After you found out which is the right one, you also need the Getter function for this property, too.

In the TCA of the table you must also configure the field as "passthrough".

**Path of Satan:** Use some ViewHelper to get the raw record from your database and then take the field from the result.